# Wordpress Ajax Javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

The following JQuery code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8. I also tried it on my phone and it doesn't work. I also looked at the code and there were no extra commas.

In IE8 the error points to...

> $(document).on('click', '.**arrow**-up', function () {

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


        ajax_url = "<?php
                echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
?>";
        // Make your AJAX request on document ready:
            (function ($) {
                $(document).on('click', '.del_btn', function () {
                var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');
                var my_data = {
                    action: 'deleter_code', // This is required so WordPress knows which function to use
                    delete_id: del_id
                };
                $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function (data) {
                    if (data == 'true') {
                        $('#' + del_id).remove();
                    } else {
                        alert("Could not be deleted");
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
            (function ($) {
             $(document).on('click', '.arrow-up', function () {
                var user_id = $(this).attr('rel');
                var my_data = {
                    action: 'arrow_handler', // This is required so WordPress knows which function to use
                    move_id: user_id,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    arrow_status: 'up'
                };
                $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function (data) {
                   var objprase=$.parseJSON(data); // now obj is a json object
                    if (objprase.true == 'true') {
                        $('#blog-table').replaceWith( objprase.text );
                    } else {
                        alert(objprase.true);
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);         
        (function ($) {
             $(document).on('click', '.arrow-down', function () {
                var user_id = $(this).attr('rel');
                var my_data = {
                    action: 'arrow_handler', // This is required so WordPress knows which function to use
                    move_id: user_id,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    arrow_status: 'down'
                };
                $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function (data) {
                   var objprase=$.parseJSON(data); // now obj is a json object
                    if (objprase.true == 'true') {
                        $('#blog-table').replaceWith( objprase.text );
                    } else {
                        alert(objprase.true);
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? Are you using the migrate plugin also? The newer versions of jQuery (2+ i think) do not support older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing all instances of `objprase.true` to `objprase['true']`.  `true` is a reserved keyword.